# How can you make part of an @Embed string in AS3 pull from a constant?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Basically let's saying you have the following line in MXML:

```
<s:Image left="0" top="0" source="@Embed(source='images/outline.png')" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" id="img" alpha="0.2"/>
```

What if you want the part about "images/" to be pulled from a constant and not hard-coded directly?  Is there a way to do this?  If so how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you won't be able to have a constant inside the `Embed` statement.

What you can do though is use the `-compiler.source-path` to add a top-level `assets` folder as folder for assets.